# Blazor Server AD Group Authentication - Not authorized

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am attempting to protect certain pages in my Blazor Server App using Active Directory Groups.

I have setup a group with the type "Security" in AD and taken note of the Object Id.

In the Startup.cs I have the following code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("WarehouseUser", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("directoryGroup", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"));

            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
```

I have decorated my index.razor as below:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "WarehouseUser")]
```

But, when i hit the index page, even though i am definitely a member of this group in AD I get the error

> Not authorized

I have also confirmed that the claim to the group is coming across with the following code in an unprotected page:

```
AuthenticationState authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
ClaimsPrincipal user = authState.User;
var g2 = user.Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("groups")).ToList();
```

Can anyone offer any help please?

Comment: What are you using as a `<group object id>`? The objectSID, objectGUID or SamAccountName? So far, I have only used the SamAccountName and it worked. (Not saying, that GUID/SID won't work.)

Comment: @Edgar.Bro I am using the "Object Id" which is a guid. How do i find my SamAccountName to test please?

Comment: There are multiple ways to find out the SamAccountName of a group. If you are familiar with PowerShell, you could execute `(Get-ADGroup "<Group-Identifier>").SamAccountName` on a domain machine with the AD-SnapIn installed (e.g. Domain Controllers), or you can use the "Active Directory Users and Computers"-SnapIn of mmc.exe. (Honestly, I think googling how to get the SamAccountName of an AD-group would return better explainations.)

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

the code in Startup.cs should be this:

```
options.AddPolicy("WarehouseUser", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("groups", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"));
```

**directoryGroup** should have been **groups**

HTH